# Error in python code of tictactoe game

Tags: python, tkinter, tic-tac-toe

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
tk=Tk()
tk.title("Tic Tac Toe")

click=True

def checker(buttons):
    global click
    if buttons[text]==" " and click==True:
        buttons[text]="X"
        click=False
    elif buttons[text]==" " and click==False:
        buttons[text]="O"
        click=True
    elif(button1[text]=="X" and button2[text]=="X" and button3[text]=="X" or
        button4[text]=="X" and button5[text]=="X" and button6[text]=="X" or
        button7[text]=="X" and button8[text]=="X" and button9[text]=="X" or
        button1[text]=="X" and button5[text]=="X" and button9[text]=="X" or
        button3[text]=="X" and button5[text]=="X" and button7[text]=="X" or
        button1[text]=="X" and button4[text]=="X" and button7[text]=="X" or
        button2[text]=="X" and button5[text]=="X" and button8[text]=="X" or
        button3[text]=="X" and button6[text]=="X" and button9[text]=="X"):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Winner X:You won the game")

    elif(button1[text]=="O" and button2[text]=="O" and button3[text]=="O" or
        button4[text]=="O" and button5[text]=="O" and button6[text]=="O" or
        button7[text]=="O" and button8[text]=="O" and button9[text]=="O" or
        button1[text]=="O" and button5[text]=="O" and button9[text]=="O" or
        button3[text]=="O" and button5[text]=="O" and button7[text]=="O" or
        button1[text]=="O" and button4[text]=="O" and button7[text]=="O" or
        button2[text]=="O" and button5[text]=="O" and button8[text]=="O" or
        button3[text]=="O" and button6[text]=="O" and button9[text]=="O"):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Winner O:You won the game")

buttons=StringVar()

button1=Button(tk,text=" ",font=('Times 26 bold'),height=4,width=8,command=lambda:checker(button1))
button1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=S+N+E+W)

button2=Button(tk,text=" ",font=('Times 26 bold'),height=4,width=8,command=lambda:checker(button2))
button2.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=S+N+E+W)

button3=Button(tk,text=" ",font=('Times 26 bold'),height=4,width=8,command=lambda:checker(button3))
button3.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=S+N+E+W)

button4=Button(tk,text=" ",font=('Times 26 bold'),height=4,width=8,command=lambda:checker(button4))
button4.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=S+N+E+W)

button5=Button(tk,text=" ",font=('Times 26 bold'),height=4,width=8,command=lambda:checker(button5))
button5.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=S+N+E+W)

button6=Button(tk,text=" ",font=('Times 26 bold'),height=4,width=8,command=lambda:checker(button6))
button6.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky=S+N+E+W)

button7=Button(tk,text=" ",font=('Times 26 bold'),height=4,width=8,command=lambda:checker(button7))
button7.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=S+N+E+W)

button8=Button(tk,text=" ",font=('Times 26 bold'),height=4,width=8,command=lambda:checker(button8))
button8.grid(row=2,column=2,sticky=S+N+E+W)

tk.mainloop()
```

[this is the screenshot of the name error which is diplayed on clicking a button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUBhq.png)

Reference-https://www.skillshare.com/classes/Creating-a-TIC-TAC-TOE-game-using-Python-and-Tkinter/886857159

How can I solve this error?

Comment: you never define what text is just like the error said

Comment: Use brackets on `text`. Like this `buttons["text"]`

Answer (score 1):

Your error was:

> NameError: name 'text' is not defined.

Check your 10 number line code. You use `buttons[text]` but here `text` wasn't defined previously. That's why you got this error.

Just change `buttons[text]` to `buttons["text"]` and put all `text` into `"text"`. It will solve your problem.

**Editted code:**

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
tk=Tk()
tk.title("Tic Tac Toe")

click=True

def checker(buttons):
    global click
    if buttons["text"]==" " and click==True:
        buttons["text"]="X"
        click=False
    elif buttons["text"]==" " and click==False:
        buttons["text"]="O"
        click=True
    elif(button1["text"]=="X" and button2["text"]=="X" and button3["text"]=="X" or
        button4["text"]=="X" and button5["text"]=="X" and button6["text"]=="X" or
        button7["text"]=="X" and button8["text"]=="X" and button9["text"]=="X" or
        button1["text"]=="X" and button5["text"]=="X" and button9["text"]=="X" or
        button3["text"]=="X" and button5["text"]=="X" and button7["text"]=="X" or
        button1["text"]=="X" and button4["text"]=="X" and button7["text"]=="X" or
        button2["text"]=="X" and button5["text"]=="X" and button8["text"]=="X" or
        button3["text"]=="X" and button6["text"]=="X" and button9["text"]=="X"):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Winner X:You won the game")

    elif(button1["text"]=="O" and button2["text"]=="O" and button3["text"]=="O" or
        button4["text"]=="O" and button5["text"]=="O" and button6["text"]=="O" or
        button7["text"]=="O" and button8["text"]=="O" and button9["text"]=="O" or
        button1["text"]=="O" and button5["text"]=="O" and button9["text"]=="O" or
        button3["text"]=="O" and button5["text"]=="O" and button7["text"]=="O" or
        button1["text"]=="O" and button4["text"]=="O" and button7["text"]=="O" or
        button2["text"]=="O" and button5["text"]=="O" and button8["text"]=="O" or
        button3["text"]=="O" and button6["text"]=="O" and button9["text"]=="O"):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Winner O:You won the game")

buttons=StringVar()

button1=Button(tk,text=" ",font=('Times 26 bold'),height=4,width=8,command=lambda:checker(button1))
button1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=S+N+E+W)

button2=Button(tk,text=" ",font=('Times 26 bold'),height=4,width=8,command=lambda:checker(button2))
button2.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=S+N+E+W)

button3=Button(tk,text=" ",font=('Times 26 bold'),height=4,width=8,command=lambda:checker(button3))
button3.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=S+N+E+W)

button4=Button(tk,text=" ",font=('Times 26 bold'),height=4,width=8,command=lambda:checker(button4))
button4.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=S+N+E+W)

button5=Button(tk,text=" ",font=('Times 26 bold'),height=4,width=8,command=lambda:checker(button5))
button5.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=S+N+E+W)

button6=Button(tk,text=" ",font=('Times 26 bold'),height=4,width=8,command=lambda:checker(button6))
button6.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky=S+N+E+W)

button7=Button(tk,text=" ",font=('Times 26 bold'),height=4,width=8,command=lambda:checker(button7))
button7.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=S+N+E+W)

button8=Button(tk,text=" ",font=('Times 26 bold'),height=4,width=8,command=lambda:checker(button8))
button8.grid(row=2,column=2,sticky=S+N+E+W)

tk.mainloop()
```

Hope it will works :)

Comment: This answer would be a lot better if you described what you changed. Otherwise the reader must compare line by line to the original code.

Comment: thanks!it did solve the error  @FarhadurRajaFahim But it is now showing an error at line 33.Syntax error, pointing the round closing bracket.